# Lightning not as jagged as per tutorial?

Tags: vertices, subdivision-surface, displacement

I tried to follow this guy's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqDUPZWuxok). While his lightning looked like this [image],

mine looked like this:

[image]

Basically, I would like my lightning to be more jagged like in this youtube tutorial's. How do I do so? Thanks

My Blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/lAzepA73

Answer (score 1):

You need to either scale up your mesh on Z in *Edit* mode (his mesh is probably taller than yours), or decrease the *Size* of your textures:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for some reason, that youtube tutorial just set the size to "1", yet had quite a bit of jagges?

Comment: In that case his mesh is probably taller than yours (on Z)